# How do I capture stdout/stderr output from program running in a new process using apr?

Tags: c, stdout, pipe, apr

The question is quite simple: how do I capture and redirect to a file the stderr/stdout output produced by child program, running in a new process, created using Apache Portable Runtime's [`apr_proc_create`](http://apr.apache.org/docs/apr/1.4/group__apr__thread__proc.html#gab51dd90b98d365a969f0ec5c7bef4e14).

The ultimate task is to run an external command with some arguments in a separate process (preferably, but not mandatory) and redirect it's output to a file.

So far I've got the following code (removed checks for clarity):

```
apr_procattr_t *attr;
apr_proc_t newproc;

const char *progname;
const char *args[100];

// progname and args are populated with data here

apr_procattr_create(&attr, p);
apr_procattr_io_set(attr, APR_CHILD_BLOCK, APR_CHILD_BLOCK, APR_CHILD_BLOCK);
apr_procattr_cmdtype_set(attr, APR_PROGRAM_PATH);
apr_proc_create(&newproc, progname, args, NULL, attr, p);
```

Using this code, the output of child process are suppressed (at least I don't see it in the console), but it's not redirected to a file. Using `APR_NO_PIPE` instead of `APR_CHILD_BLOCK` results in flushing the child's output into parent stdout/stderr

APR appears to have very little 'cookbook' recipes, so I was unable to google it.

Any hints or suggestions? Non-APR solutions are welcome, provided they are as simple and clear as the code I've posted.

P.S. running on Debian 6(Linux `2.6.32-5-686`), gcc `4.4.5`, but I think it's irrelevant. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [test cases for APR](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/apr/apr/trunk/test/) contain a lot of useful examples. In your case, you should have a look into [testproc.c](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/apr/apr/trunk/test/testproc.c):

COPYRIGHT NOTICE: This code is protected by the [APL 2.0](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0)

```
/* Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
 * contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
 * this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
 * The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
 * (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
 * the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

static void test_file_redir(abts_case *tc, void *data)
{
    apr_file_t *testout = NULL;
    apr_file_t *testerr = NULL;
    apr_off_t offset;
    apr_status_t rv;
    const char *args[2];
    apr_procattr_t *attr;
    apr_file_t *testfile = NULL;
    apr_size_t length;
    char *buf;

    testfile = NULL;
    rv = apr_file_open(&testfile, "data/stdin",
                       APR_FOPEN_READ | APR_FOPEN_WRITE | APR_FOPEN_CREATE | APR_FOPEN_EXCL,
                       APR_OS_DEFAULT, p);
    ABTS_INT_EQUAL(tc, APR_SUCCESS, rv);
    rv = apr_file_open(&testout, "data/stdout",
                       APR_FOPEN_READ | APR_FOPEN_WRITE | APR_FOPEN_CREATE | APR_FOPEN_EXCL,
                       APR_OS_DEFAULT, p);
    ABTS_INT_EQUAL(tc, APR_SUCCESS, rv);
    rv = apr_file_open(&testerr, "data/stderr",
                       APR_FOPEN_READ | APR_FOPEN_WRITE | APR_FOPEN_CREATE | APR_FOPEN_EXCL,
                       APR_OS_DEFAULT, p);
    ABTS_INT_EQUAL(tc, APR_SUCCESS, rv);

    length = strlen(TESTSTR);
    apr_file_write(testfile, TESTSTR, &length);
    offset = 0;
    rv = apr_file_seek(testfile, APR_SET, &offset);
    ABTS_INT_EQUAL(tc, APR_SUCCESS, rv);
    ABTS_ASSERT(tc, "File position mismatch, expected 0", offset == 0);

    rv = apr_procattr_create(&attr, p);
    ABTS_INT_EQUAL(tc, APR_SUCCESS, rv);
    rv = apr_procattr_child_in_set(attr, testfile, NULL);
    ABTS_INT_EQUAL(tc, APR_SUCCESS, rv);
    rv = apr_procattr_child_out_set(attr, testout, NULL);
    ABTS_INT_EQUAL(tc, APR_SUCCESS, rv);
    rv = apr_procattr_child_err_set(attr, testerr, NULL);
    ABTS_INT_EQUAL(tc, APR_SUCCESS, rv);
    rv = apr_procattr_dir_set(attr, "data");
    ABTS_INT_EQUAL(tc, APR_SUCCESS, rv);
    rv = apr_procattr_cmdtype_set(attr, APR_PROGRAM_ENV);
    ABTS_INT_EQUAL(tc, APR_SUCCESS, rv);

    args[0] = "proc_child";
    args[1] = NULL;

    rv = apr_proc_create(&newproc, proc_child, args, NULL, 
                         attr, p);
    ABTS_INT_EQUAL(tc, APR_SUCCESS, rv);

    rv = apr_proc_wait(&newproc, NULL, NULL, APR_WAIT);
    ABTS_INT_EQUAL(tc, APR_CHILD_DONE, rv);

    offset = 0;
    rv = apr_file_seek(testout, APR_SET, &offset);
    ABTS_INT_EQUAL(tc, APR_SUCCESS, rv);

    length = 256;
    buf = apr_pcalloc(p, length);
    rv = apr_file_read(testout, buf, &length);
    ABTS_INT_EQUAL(tc, APR_SUCCESS, rv);
    ABTS_STR_EQUAL(tc, TESTSTR, buf);


    apr_file_close(testfile);
    apr_file_close(testout);
    apr_file_close(testerr);

    rv = apr_file_remove("data/stdin", p);;
    ABTS_INT_EQUAL(tc, APR_SUCCESS, rv);
    rv = apr_file_remove("data/stdout", p);;
    ABTS_INT_EQUAL(tc, APR_SUCCESS, rv);
    rv = apr_file_remove("data/stderr", p);;
    ABTS_INT_EQUAL(tc, APR_SUCCESS, rv);
}
```

Comment: Looks like that's it, hovewer I can't verify it right now. Anyway, thank you, I'll check it out and update/accept as soon as I can.